# Which part of my code is causing a "Time-Out Error" and why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I am trying to solve this problem on Hackerrank:https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/climbing-the-leaderboard. The problem statement basically states that there are two set of scores one of players and other of Alice and we have to use [dense ranking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranking#Dense_ranking_(%221223%22_ranking)) and display Alice's rank when compared to other player's scores. It is giving me Time-Out error on large test-cases. I have used the forum suggestions on Hackerrank already and was successful, but specifically I am curious to know the problem in my code. Here is my code:

```
class Dict(dict):

    def __init__(self):
        self=dict()

    def add(self,key,value):
        self[key]=value

def climbingLeaderboard(scores, alice):

    alice_rank=[]
    for i in range(len(alice)):
        scores.append(alice[i])
        a=list(set(scores))
        a.sort(reverse=True)
        obj=Dict()
        b=1
        for j in a:
            obj.add(j,b)
            b+=1
        if alice[i] in obj:
            alice_rank.append(obj[alice[i]])
    scores.remove(alice[i])        
    return alice_rank
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of problems in your code but the most important one is the following.

```
...
scores.append(alice[i])
a=list(set(scores))
a.sort(reverse=True)
...
```

On each iteration you add Alice's score to `scores` and then sort `scores`. The cost here is already `O(nlog(n))`, where `n` - number of elements in `scores`. Thus, your total time complexity becomes `O(n*n*log(n))`. That's too much because `n` can reach `200000` and so for your solution it can be up to `200000*200000*log(200000)` operations.

Of course, there's another problem:

```
...
for j in a:
    obj.add(j,b)
    b+=1
...
```

But it's still not as bad as the previous one since the loop time complexity is `O(n)`.

There exists a `O(n*log(n))` time complexity solution. I'll give you an overall idea so that you can easily implement it yourself.

- If you recall that players with duplicate scores share the same position in the leaderboard then you can convert your `scores` to an array without duplicates as `list(set(scores))` before your loop. In that case, the first position corresponds to the highest score, the second one to the second highest score and so on (the initial array is sorted in decreasing order per problem statement).
- Given the step above, for each `score` of Alice you can find a position  in the array at which the player's score is less or equal to `score`. The lookup will take `O(log(n))` because the array is sorted. For instance, if scores of players are `40, 30, 10` and a score of Alice is `35`, then the found position will be `2` (for the algorithm description I consider that the first index starts from `1`) as `30` occupies this position, This position is the **ACTUAL** position of Alice in the leaderboard and so can be printed right away.
- Another tip - you can use [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/bisect.html) module for performing a binary search in the  array.

So, the overall time complexity of the proposed solution is `O(n*log(n))`. It will pass all the test cases (I've tried it).

Answer (score 1):

Performing repeated sort (a.sort(reverse=True)) consumes a lot of time. I had the same problem. If you read the question, you will find that the scores are input in sorted (ascending or descending). **The trick is to exploit this inherent ordering of input.**

One more thing, your code's time complexity is O(n^2) due to nested loop, whereas the forum you spoke if may be doing it with O(n) (not sure).